# Where is the Arial Narrow font on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, fonts, file-location, embedded-fonts

If I open up MS Word, I can see Arial Narrow in the font list (so I know it is on my machine somwhere).

But when I go to c:\Windows\Fonts or to c:\Windows\winsxs I can not seem to find any file that is Arial Narrow.

**Any one know where this file is?**

(I need to make a custom Arial Narrow font for a memory constrained label printer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Where is the Arial Narrow font on Windows?

> FYI, when I open C:\Windows\Fonts in Explorer I see Arial.  When I
> double click it, I get a Font family details screen:
>
> [image]
>
> Right-click > Properties on the Arial Narrow font in the above window
> yields:
>
> [image]

Source [Arial Narrow Font is missing!](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/arial-narrow-font-is-missing/98cfeeaa-dd34-4ba4-884a-2346744b5f05)